# cloud_sql_proxy uses unspecified credential file instead of gcloud auth login

Tags: gcloud, cloud-sql-proxy

My computer rebooted and for some reasons I ignore, `cloud_sql_proxy` tries to use a credential file instead of my gcloud auth login:

```
cloud_sql_proxy --instances=instance:region:orcadb=tcp:54321
2022/09/06 12:43:07 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {Current = 8500, Max = 
9223372036854775807}
2022/09/06 12:43:07 using credential file for authentication; email=example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2022/09/06 12:43:08 errors parsing config:
googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized
```

I checked that my gcloud login is correct by using `gcloud auth login`, and then checking using `gcloud config list account`.
I also tried adding the flag `--enable_iam_login` to the command.
My permissions are already set to owner.

How can I use `cloud_sql_proxy` without the credential file? Thanks! :)

Comment: Does the service account have the Cloud SQL Client role?

Answer (score 0):

If no credential file is pointed for `cloud_sql_proxy` then it takes the file path from the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env. var first.
You have to check if this env var has a value

```
echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%
```

If yes then clean it up

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

Now the `cloud_sql_proxy` should take the current glcoud account